# jQuery UI Autocomplete: source of object is not a function, how to use external url?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to get the jQuery UI autocomplete working with a URL (since I am working with several thousand records, and this seemed like the correct solution), yet I am getting an error in JavaScript and I cannot figure out why.

**Error Message**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'source' of object #<Object> is not a function 
assets/js/plugins/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js:45
```

**HTML Form Field**

```
<input class='autocomplete-remote' name='client_id' data-remote-source='<?= base_url(); ?>/clients/json_list'/>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(".autocomplete-remote").autocomplete({                                                                                                        
    source : $(this).attr('data-remote-source')                                                                                                 
});
```

**clients/json_list output**

```
[{ "label" : "John Doe", "value" : "1"}, {"label" : "Jane Doe" : "value" : "2"}]
```

My understanding of the documentation was that if source was a string, it would be used as a URL and fetch data from that source. but this is not working.

Comment: did you try this example http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp  ?

Comment: @Amitd no, but it sounds like according to the docs that shouldn't be nessecary: "Autocomplete can be customized to work with various data sources, by just specifying the source option. A data source can be: an Array with local data,
a String, specifying a URL, a Callback..." so I don't understand why this is a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your javascript is wrong `$(this)` does not refer to `$(".autocomplete-remote")`.  They are on the same scope as the options object is not inside a function.

It should look like this:

```
$(".autocomplete-remote").autocomplete({                                                                                                        
    source :  $(".autocomplete-remote").attr('data-remote-source')                                                                                                 
});
```

OR

```
var elem = $(".autocomplete-remote");
elem.autocomplete({                                                                                                        
    source :  elemn.attr('data-remote-source')                                                                                                 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Also point 3 @ [jQuery: Autocomplete Tutorial](http://www.giveupalready.com/content.php?187-jQuery-Autocomplete-Tutorial)

> If you use this method, the data source must be on the same domain as
>   the requesting page.